# Why my angular HTTP request can't GET on local Django server?

Tags: django, angular

I made an Angular application able use an online api to get a json and do stuff.
But, although the json is the same, if I try to change only the url of the json by setting a local url of a server written in django, angular would seem not to connect anymore ...

My question is, why if with an online cloud server works, with a local one wouldn't?

I tried making this server "on cloud" opening the router's port, also setting up a ddns, and using postman or a browser it seems to work, but when i try to connect with angular it still doesn't get the data...

I am sure 100% that the server answer, with the right json data, because django prints on console that he received a HTTP GET request :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/bYHch.png

I remind you that the HTTP angular request worked with another api, but i will still show up some code :

```
export class ProdottoService {
  private prodotti: Array<ProdottoModel>;
  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) {
    this.prodotti = new Array<ProdottoModel>();

    var url:string = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/saniyusuf/406b843afdfb9c6a86e25753fe2761f4/raw/523c324c7fcc36efab8224f9ebb7556c09b69a14/Film.JSON";
    var local_url:string = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/films/?format=json";

    httpClient.get(local_url)
        .subscribe((films : Array<Object> ) => {
          films.forEach((film => {
                this.prodotti.push(new ProdottoModel(film));
            }));
          }
        );

  }
  getProdotti(): Array<ProdottoModel> {
    return this.prodotti;
  }
}
```

Result using external api :

https://i.stack.imgur.com/cvIiP.png

Thanks in advace for any help :3

***-- EDIT -- IS A CORS ISSUE***

In django settings.py file :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:4200'
)


INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
```

But i don't know if there's a way to set-up CORS settings in Angular

Comment: Here you are the code of the server django, and the front-end angular code :
https://github.com/fl0wo/films-angular-django

Comment: What makes you think that you aren't fetching the json? If you're using Chrome can you please open the network tab and see if your application is making the call (your server seems to be getting a call anyways?).

Comment: This is what happens when refresh the tab on Chrome : http://i.imgur.com/ZVEWSHd.png 
And yes, the server obviusly notifiy me that he just answered to a GET request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on feedback, this is a CORS issue.  Your Django server is getting the requests and responding because localhost is an implicitly trusted domain in Django's dev environment, but it isn't configured properly to set the cross origin header, so the browser is not allowing your app to see the response because the server hasn't authorized the domain explicitly.

The problem here is that you've set CORS white list like this:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( 'localhost:8000', '127.0.0.1:4200' )
```

it needs to be like this:

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ( 'localhost:4200' )
```

angular runs on localhost, not 127.0.0.1, even though that's what localhost is an alias for, your browser still differentiates them for CORS. Also, you do not need to whitelist the domain your serving off of, that's not crossing any origin as it's the same origin.

Comment: That makes sense, but it never logs anything... even putting an "alert" method it seems to don't even enter on the subscribe callback...
http://i.imgur.com/hVv5ZBR.png

Comment: Bryan: It looks like an array to me, but the screenshot cut off part of the opening square bracket. Good thinking though. Florian: you can also add "debugger;" instead of the console.log, which will stop the code and you can explore what's going on if the dev console is open.

Comment: @FlorianSabani nothing ever shows in your log but your sure the constructor is being called (IE you've put some logging in before the request)? That sounds like for some reason angular is choking on the request. Is there some kind of CORS issue? though that should definitely log...

Comment: @StevenLacks possible, screenshot is cut off but looks like chrome and my chrome makes JSON pretty, either that or a CORS issue is my best guesses at this.

Comment: I dont know if theres a "silent CORS issue" i only know that seems everything works without error logs, and i defined on the django server the CORS_WHITELIST so i am sure anyone can connect to the localhost:8000 server... :/, infact when i connect with angular the server sees him and answer with the correct response, but angular seems to ignore it :C

Comment: @FlorianSabani when you load your angular app, do you see the request go out on the network tab? Can you post that screenshot?

Comment: @bryan60 you got it! i dont know why i didnt before... anyway how can i fix now? 
http://i.imgur.com/rPVLouS.png
Thanks for everything guys!

Comment: Your cors whitelist isn't set up correctly. Post that config.

Comment: On django "settings.py" file :

```
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
    'localhost:8000',
    '127.0.0.1:4200'
)

```
And of corse :
MIDDLEWARE = [  # Or MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES on Django < 1.10
    ...
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    ...
]
And installed apps :
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    ...
    'corsheaders',
    ...
)

Comment: nvm i see the issue, answered.

Comment: You are a god bryan thanks a lot!
I dont know why i didn't even checked... i was preatty sure wasn't my fault...

Answer (score 0):

In your screenshot, it looks like the response is type "document..." something. The simplest fix, with only the code here, is to convert the string to JSON.

```
JSON.parse(films)
```

This is the wrong answer, because it's being set to that because of the CORS issue in the other answers.

Comment: Angular and Django are both generally very good about setting their headers correctly without manual intervention.  Given that he said in other comments that he isn't even getting a logging statement inside his subscribe callback, I think something else is going on.

Comment: It's explicitly getting back a MIME-type "document"

Comment: The browser handled that request though as he hit his API endpoint directly via the browser. Document is the default content type for direct requests from the URL bar. Same type shows for the remote URL when hit directly.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Content_negotiation/List_of_default_Accept_values

Comment: I did say "getting back" but I should have said "using."

Comment: Doesn't matter, the prime domain you hit via the URL bar is always coerced to Document type as the browser is always displaying a document and only accepts Document. this is a CORS issue.